# Sharing a route that's under two middlewares

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have a route that I use within my Laravel app,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
      Route::post('user/submission-form/validate', [ApiUserSubmissionController::class, 'validateUserSubmissionForm']);
})
```

Although now I'm building an app and need to use the same route. The apps routes are encapsulated by the `['auth:sanctum']` middleware. The `auth:api` requires the API key and sanctum has another key that you pass in. Is there a way I can make this route work for both without having to duplicate it and naming it something different?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
      // I need to use that route here too
})
```

Comment: making a new middleware that works for one of them at a time.

Comment: @N69S Is there an example? I'm trying to wrap my head around how that would work

Comment: As a logic, it's wrong to implement two auth middleware to the same route. You must uniform the way you authenticate this route. As an ability, the only way to handle this by adding new middleware to implement both auth.

Comment: just open the two existing middleware and create a new one with the mix/logic you need in the `Handle()` method. you can find the classes in the kernel.php file (class alias and declared 
middlewares)

Comment: If that is your actual code then you can either use `auth:api,sanctum` as your middleware or extract the function as a variable (e.g. `$routes = function() { Route::post(....) })` and use it in both (e.g. `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], $routes)`